# How to interpolate matrix "between values" values in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, interpolation

Let's say I have a 3-by-3 matrix of the following values in Matlab:

```
A = [1 3 5;  3 5 7;  5 7 9];
```

How can I interpolate my matrix for example to be:

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5;  2 3 4 5 6;  3 4 5 6 7;  4 5 6 7 8;  5 6 7 8 9];
```

So in this case all the integer "between values" were added in the matrix. How can I do this in the general case with chosen precision? For example If my matrix is again:

```
A = [1 3 5;  3 5 7;  5 7 9];
```

How can I interpolate A to be:

```
A = [1 1.2 1.4 1.6 1.8 2.0 2.2 2.4 2.6 2.8 3 3.2 .........4.8 5;  1.2 1.4 1.6 1.8 2.0  .......... 5.2; 1.4 1.6 .... etc. ];
```

Hope my question is clear =) I want to interpolate the "between values" with chosen precision, both in X and Y direction.

I came across with **interp2**-function, but I'm not sure how to use it and thought If someone familiar with this problem could tell the answer faster =)

Thank you any help!

Comment: What does "Chosen precision" mean? Explain yourself. And if you already found interp2, then why not try it? Don't use us as your manual because you are too lazy to read the help yourself. How will our spending the time to type in an answer, then you reading OUR answer be faster than you just reading the help?

Comment: By "Chosen precision" I mean that I want to interpolate between numbers 1 and 3 just the integers i.e. 1, 2, 3 or I want it to be more precise i.e. 1, 1.2, 1.4, ..., 2, ...3 or I could do 1, 1.1, 1.2, ..., 1.9, 2, 2.1, ..., 2.9, 3 or 1, 1.01, 1.02, ...., 3. I hope that clarifies =) The reason I asked this question was because some of the terminology in the manual confused me and was hoping to get someone to clarify it =) It makes more sense to ask someone who knows how to do it in 1 min than trying to figure it out yourself 1 hour unless the manual is unambiguous,

Comment: because there might be certain variables you're not familiar with yet :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `help interp2`:

> ZI = INTERP2(X,Y,Z,XI,YI) interpolates to find ZI, the values of the
>       underlying 2-D function Z at the points in matrices XI and YI.
>       Matrices X and Y specify the points at which the data Z is given.
>
> ```
> XI can be a row vector, in which case it specifies a matrix with
> constant columns. Similarly, YI can be a column vector and it 
> specifies a matrix with constant rows. 
>
> ZI = INTERP2(Z,XI,YI) assumes X=1:N and Y=1:M where [M,N]=SIZE(Z).
> ZI = INTERP2(Z,NTIMES) expands Z by interleaving interpolates between
> every element, working recursively for NTIMES.  INTERP2(Z) is the
> same as INTERP2(Z,1).
> ```

So, for your example,

```
 >> A = [1 3 5;  3 5 7;  5 7 9];
 >> A2 = interp2(A, 1)  % call of type INTERP2(Z,NTIMES)

 A2 =
     1     2     3     4     5
     2     3     4     5     6
     3     4     5     6     7
     4     5     6     7     8
     5     6     7     8     9

 >> [X,Y] = meshgrid(1:0.1:3);
 >> A3 = interp(A, X,Y)  % call of type INTERP2(Z,XI,YI)
 >> 

 A3 =
     1.0000    1.2000    1.4000    1.6000    1.8000    2.0000    2.2000 ...
     1.2000    1.4000    1.6000    1.8000    2.0000    2.2000    2.4000 ...
     1.4000    1.6000    1.8000    ...
     ...
```